# How to Add month to a date while keeping the last month of a given month

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

Can somebody help me on how to add month to a date while keeping the last day of that month?

Suppose I have updated the first data on 2013-01-29, so when adding one month to that date, it will be 2013-02-28. But everytime I add one month again on the latest date, it becomes 2013-03-28 but it must be 2013-03-29. What would be the perfect command in mysql query that I can use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are preserving your "First data" somewhere, it is impossible to build any logic to achieve the functionality you are expecting.

Please elaborate in detail your data model and business use case

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as long as you can get 'some' form of timestamp for the following month. Then you can do this:

```
SELECT '2013-02-28 23:59:59' + INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY('2013-03-28 23:59:59')) DAY
```

First supply the original date, then supply the LAST_DAY() function with a timestamp from any point in the next month. This returns the last day timestamp and we take the 'DAY' portion of this and add this interval to the original timestamp.

I would argue that this should probably happen within localisation of your business logic however.